# Giving emphasis for one things saying other thing is not focused by the community

Tags: conjunctions, negation

I want to write the following idea in my abstract:

> The vast majority of works on building model reconstructions from
>   aerial data mainly focus on roof modelling, **but** not façade models.

BUT I feel, **but** in this sentence is breaking the flow of the sentence. In this type of situation, how can we avoid the awkwardness and get a smooth sentence?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> The vast majority of works on building model reconstructions from aerial data mainly focus on roof modelling, [and] not façade models.

or

> The vast majority of works on building model reconstructions from aerial data mainly focus on roof modelling, as opposed to façade models.

Comment: Option 1 could work without the _and_, too: _...focus on roof modelling, not façade models._